# Setting two different baud rates in AVR USART

Tags: avr, usart

I need to set baud rate of USART to 9600 to receive data from PC. Then I need to change it to 300 to send data to other device. Can AVR work with different baud rate ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can AVR work with different baud rate ?

If the controller has multiple USART ports, each can run at a different baud rate.
You can also change the baud rate for each port at any time. Technically there are some minor pitfalls like changing speed while a transmission is ongoing may corrupt data.